# How can I avoid autocoercion in Couchbase queries?

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++, coercion

An N1QL query has a filter `WHERE myField < $value`.

From experimenting, I see that Couchbase  orders the types as follows:  boolean < integer < string < JsonArray, even though from my perspective they should not be comparable.

For example,  any  boolean evaluates as less than any  integer; any  integer is  less than all strings. (`9223372036854775807` (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) evaluates as  less than `""` (empty string).)

I want to avoid this type-coercion. I want `"A" < 1` and `"A" > 1` to be `false` and not to return such values from the  filter.  (And also, it seems that in Javascript, both these expressions are `false`, as they should be.)

What are the coercion rules? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered the collation order of N1QL. Here is a fuller explanation:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datatypes.html

If you want to avoid this comparison across types, you can add a clause using the TYPE() function to verify that the two elements being compared are of the same type.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/typefun.html

So rather than having `$A > 3` you would have `($A > 3) AND (TYPE($A) = TYPE(3))`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the reason for coercing types for collation? I can't think of any use cases where would want  9223372036854775807<""

Comment: I think the early designers of the query engine simply wanted to create a total order of all values. The alternative would have been to leave the matter undecided, so if your results had integers and strings in the ORDER BY expression, the integers would be sorted and the strings would be sorted, but they could be interleaved in any way at all.

Comment: To expand on Johan's point, JSON does not have a fixed schema - it's possible to have a field that has type string in some documents, integer in others, and an object-value in others. Defining a total ordering permits ORDER BY of such fields.

Comment: @JohanLarson and ebenH, That makes sense for ORDER BY, but I am asking  about WHERE clauses--filters, If I query WHERE age >30; and a Document has age="Foo", I do not expect the object to be returned.

Comment: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/why-does-n1ql-use-collation-order-for-where-filters/20846 I will appreciate any answers there.

I posted this to the Couchbase Forum,which is more suited to this kind of discussion.